# Function assertIn causes the UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: django, unit-testing

During the test for my Django 1.9 project I get an error:

[image]

Python swears on this code:

```
def test_students_list(self):
    # make request to the server to get homepage page
    response = self.client.get(self.url)

    # do we have student name on a page?
    self.assertIn('Vitaliy', response.content)
```

How to set the same encoding for the arguments in function assertIn?
I tried so:

> self.assertIn(u"Vitaliy", response.content.decode('utf8'))

The result is the same...

P.S. I have Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I have the same, it's because the response contains unicode but HTTPResponse.content is being given to you as ascii. I cannot work out how to change this. The system running the code has UTF-8 in the default locale, Django's defaults are for responses to be as unicode. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to define your Python source code encoding using:

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

As suggest in [PEP 0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.content

The HTTPResponse.content is noted in the docs as being a bytestring (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L225), it *should* be encoded as `DEFAULT_CHARSET` which by default is `utf-8` but in both our cases this doesn't seem to get through to the test.

My solution is to tell Python request.content should have unicode encoding:

```
def test_students_list(self):
    # make request to the server to get homepage page
    response = self.client.get(self.url)

    # do we have student name on a page?
    self.assertIn('Vitaliy', unicode(response.content, encoding='utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.assertContains(response, 'Vitaliy')` instead.