# AssertIn unittest with strings

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am writing some unittest, want to use AssertIn for string comparison.

I have a instanciated object Cooper, having property FBI, that returns a str type

The Code is simple the class to test:

```
 class Cooper():
    ...

    @property
    def FBI(self):
        return self._FBI
```

And in the unittest :

```
Coop = Cooper()
...
p = os.path.join('/home/twinpeaks','CooperFBIdkaéfjkfjfdéjdakél')
print(Coop.FBI,type(Coop.FBI),type(p))
print (Coop.FBI in p)
self.assertIn(Coop.FBI,p)
```

I checked that the first line of my code is # -- coding: utf-8 --, after reading this [Function assertIn causes the UnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36004324/function-assertin-causes-the-unicodedecodeerror)

But I get the output :

```
 twinpeaks/CopperFBI /home/twinpeaks/CooperFBIdkaéfjkfjfdéjdakél'  <class 'str'> <class 'str'>
 True
 E.s
 ======================================================================
 ERROR: test_class_Path (Code.tests.UtilsTests.UtilsTest)
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/twinpeaks/PythonCode/Code/tests/UtilsTests.py", line 68, in    test_Cooper
 self.assertIn(Cooper.FBI,p)
 File "/home/twinpeaks/anaconda3/envs/ana3/lib/python3.6/unittest/case.py", line 1085, in assertIn
 if member not in container:
 TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType
```

What is the problem ? I'm a little bit stuck, there...

Comment: `Cooper.FBI` seems to have become `None`. What exactly is `FBI`? Could it be a property?

Comment: @KlausD. FBI is a property

Comment: That explains the change. Please add the code of the property.

Comment: @KlausD. Modified... So, what is the problem ? I suppose according to your comment that I shoud copy the string and that Cooper.FBI[:] should work, but what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: With that code `type(Cooper.FBI)` should return something like `<class 'property'>`.

Comment: @KlausD. Sorry, in the modification to write in code the sentence that explained my case, I forgot to instanciate. Didn't get why at first  `type(Cooper.FBI)` should return  `<class 'property'>`. But still a question : where should I have found the information that property won't work with `assertIn`, but they are working with the buildin `in` works ? I didn't see it in the docs ...

Comment: I did not say they don't work. They *can* behave weird, like changing their value on every call.

Comment: @KlausD. Hum... Last question, as before I admit I won't understand this ? Why the `self.assertIn(Coop.FIB[:]) trick works all the time and returns the value I'm expecting ? Or if you have a good reference that I should read to understand what you mean, feel free to post it...